# Is there a simpler way to prove that a fractional function with three variables is convex?

Tags: proof-writing, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, hessian-matrix, jensen-inequality

How to prove that f(x) is convex?

For all $$x_i>0$$
we have
$$ f(x) = \frac{1}{x_1 - \frac{1}{ x_2 - \frac{1}{x_3}  }} $$
I tried to take the second derivative (hessian matrix) but it was too long and i couldn't prove that the hessian is PSD.
Also tried the Jensen's inequality,  but again, couldn't go with it.
So, is there a simpler way to prove this function's convexity?
Is this a linear fractional function? If so, then how would it be related to convexity? (Thank you in advance.)

Comment: The function is not defined for all $x_1, x_2, x_3 > 0$, so what exactly is the domain? – Also $f(x) = 1/(x_1-a)$ for fixed $x_2, x_3$, and that is not convex on $(0, a)$.

Comment: @Martin R, It's just how it was defined in the exercise. It says "prove that this function for x_i>0 is convex." So I guess it has issues...